# Why doesn't Ubuntu provide the compiled version of emacs .el files

Tags: emacs, binary, source-packages

I just noticed that when I start emacs on MATE 20.04, the system packages it loads are source files, not their binaries.  I'm curious to know why since, as I understand, the binaries load much faster.

For example,

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...done
.
.
.
Loading personal...
Loading no-x-settings...done
Loading ssh...done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listed `*.el` files

1. are too small, too short, and over too quickly to benefit from Emacs Lisp compilation. Read them.
2. are only encountered once, at `emacs` startup.

A better usage pattern is to start `emacs` once, enable `(server-start)` in your `~/.emacs`, and use `emacsclient`to access and reaccess it.
In your `~/.bashrc`,

`export VISUAL=emacsclient
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
alias emacs="emacsclient"`

will make using `emacsclient` easier. Read `man emacsclient`.